# Coloring a map with missing data in Stata

Tags: graph, stata

I'm trying to create a choropleth world map using spmap (SSC) in Stata, with each country colored with their respective data (variable total_worker). Below is the code that I'm using to create the map:

```
colorpalette viridis, n(12) nograph reverse
local colors `r(p)'
drop if country=="Antarctica"
spmap total_worker using world_coord, id(id) clbreaks(0 5001 20001 50001 150001 1000000 50000000) clmethod(custom) ///
legend(pos(7) size(2.8) region(fcolor(gs15)) label(2 "0 to 5000") label(3 "5001 to 20000")  label(4 "20001 to 50000" )  label(5 "50001 to 150000" ) label(6 "150001 to 1000000" ) label(7 "1000000+" )) ///
fcolor("`colors'")  ocolor(white ..) osize(0.05 ..) title("2017", size(5))
```

Here world_coord is the coordinates that I created using the command:

```
shp2dta using "world_countries_2020", database(world_db) coordinates(world_coord) genid(id) replace
```

world_countries_2020 has .dbf and .shp extension in the current directory. Currently, this code will produce the following graph:

[image]

I'd want the white "No data" countries to be grey in color, and have the outline color to be white, just like other countries. How can I customize the color of the countries that has missing variable value?

This is crossposted at Statalist: https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1718616-creating-a-map-with-missing-data

Comment: You could set the missing values to a negative income, keep the "No data" label and set grey as color.

Answer (score 0):

As per the solution given in the Statalist (linked in the question), the solution is including ndfcolor(gray%30 ..) ndocolor(white ..) :

```
colorpalette viridis, n(12) nograph reverse
local colors `r(p)'
drop if country=="Antarctica"
spmap total_worker using world_coord, id(id) clbreaks(0 5001 20001 50001 150001 1000000 50000000) clmethod(custom) ///
legend(pos(7) size(2.8) region(fcolor(gs15)) label(2 "0 to 5000") label(3 "5001 to 20000")  label(4 "20001 to 50000" )  label(5 "50001 to 150000" ) label(6 "150001 to 1000000" ) label(7 "1000000+" )) ///
fcolor("`colors'")  ocolor(white ..) osize(0.05 ..) title("2017", size(5)) ndfcolor(gray%30 ..) ndocolor(white ..)
```